# Doubly Linked List Giving Mixed Results?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

This is code that my teacher gave us (just the addNode function), so tell me why when I run the input.txt with numbers like 1 2 3 4...

In Visual Studio it comes out 1, 2, 3, 4
..and on repl, it comes out 4, 3, 2, 1.

I will ask my teacher but it's the weekend, so thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct node {

int data;
node *next = NULL;
node *prev = NULL;

};

void addNode(node *&head, node *&tail, int value) {

    node *temp = new node;
    temp->data = value;
    temp->prev = NULL;

    if (!head) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        tail = temp;
    }

    else {
        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
    }
    head = temp;
}
void traverse(node *head) {
    node *current = head;

    while (current) {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *head, *tail;
    head = tail = NULL;
    int value;

    ifstream in("c:\\temp\\input.txt");

    while (!in.eof()) {
        in >> value;
        addNode(head, tail, value);
    }
    traverse(head);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a wierd way to implement a two-way linked list. I'd expect addFirst,addLast,addBefore and addAfter instead of a single addNode

Comment: Thanks, we're still in the first bits of doubly linked list so for now we only have to provide a add function to build a list, order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Given input `1 2 3 4` the correct output is `4 3 2 1`.

Notice that every time you call `addNode()` it pushes the new node **before** `head`:

```
else {
    temp->next = head;
    head->prev = temp;
}
```

and then the new node becomes the new `head`:

```
head = temp;
```

==> when you traverse over the list, the elements will be displayed in an opposite order of their insertion.

Comment: Thanks and yes I agree that the sequence should in fact be reversed, but why does Visual Studio orders it in ascending is beyond me.  Today I wrote a new addNode where the tail keeps appending and the same thing happened in Studio.  It doesn't affect my program in this case, but just curious why it's like that.